# Running two NestJS applications in the same process

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I've been working with [Express](https://expressjs.com/) for a couple of years now and recently got introduced to NestJS. I decided to experiment and write an application on this, as it seemed to me, interesting framework.

I want my application to be able to handle the following routes:

- General routes
  `/policy`, `/docs`
- API routes (with versioning)
  `/api/v1/users`, `/api/v1/chats`

In Express, this is very easy to do, but as I understand it, in NestJS everything is different. As I understand from the documentation, in NestJS you cannot set the path prefix for the entire module. You can only set a global prefix for the entire application.

The documentation also talked about the [RouterModule](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module). But I didn’t like it, because it won’t be possible to enable versioning specifically for routes /api and the use of RouterModule itself is very inconvenient. As the application grows, using the RouterModule becomes a pain.

Then I tried to convert the application to a [monorepository](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#monorepo-mode). It seems to be possible to achieve the desired functionality, but it seems inconvenient for me to run each part of the application separately. Perhaps it would be worth using [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently), but in my opinion, this is also not the best option.

As a result, I came to the following solution.
The structure of my project at the moment looks like this:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbOoV.png)

The api directory will contain all modules related to the api (it will process `/api/v1/...` routes), and everything else will be in the core (it will process `/docs`, `/policy` routes, etc.).

In fact, everything is the same as when creating a [monorepository](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#monorepo-mode), but I decided to run all this from a single main.ts

[main.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXkal.png)

And I have a question, what are the pitfalls of this solution? Will it affect performance? Are there any better options for solving my problem?

Comment: Maybe the versioning is the title you're looking for https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning#uri-versioning-type

Answer (score 0):

To enable versioning with NestJS :

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableVersioning({
  type: VersioningType.URI,
});
await app.listen(3000);
```

Then, it's true that every routes will need version in URL: `/v1/...`

But you can use `VERSION_NEUTRAL` to mark default endpoint version :

> Some controllers or routes may not care about the version and would
> have the same functionality regardless of the version. To accommodate
> this, the version can be set to VERSION_NEUTRAL symbol.
>
> An incoming request will be mapped to a VERSION_NEUTRAL controller or
> route regardless of the version sent in the request in addition to if
> the request does not contain a version at all.

So, for example, here, route /v1/users for Users V1 only :

```js
@Controller({
  version: '1',
})
export class UsersControllerV1 {
  @Get()
  getUsers()...
}
```

and another route (controller) without any version :

```js
@Controller({
  version: VERSION_NEUTRAL,
})
export class PolicyController {
  @Get()
  getPolicy()...
}
```

Note that it's possible to provide more than one unique version :

```js
version: ['1', VERSION_NEUTRAL]
```

More details on [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning#version-neutral).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But I'm interested in something else.  I want my application to be able to work with both /api routes and routes like /docs or /policy at the same time.  At the same time, /api routes can be of a certain version and have a path after the version (for example, /api/v1/users), while /docs routes do not need versions.

Comment: Yes, I understood, in my example, you will have both /v1/users (with version), and /policy (without any version needed). And if you want to remove /api prefix, just remove it from `main.ts` and add it only for api routes.

Comment: How then to achieve versioning only for api routes? And how can I make the users module process the path /api/users and not /users?

Comment: Add it on `Controller` path directly, but it's true that if you add /api prefix to each specific routes, you will have versioning as `/v1/api/users`, and not `/api/v1/users`. But do you really need to make distinction between /policy and /api/users, both are api...

Comment: Yes, I need /policy without the /api prefix. On /policy there will be an html page with the policy, and on /api there will be methods for client and server interaction.

Comment: I guess I still have to run separate applications for api and others routes, and combine them through nginx?